# Android resource linking failed when i try to compile

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

this is a demo app with empty activity it shows the error in the android studio when i compile or build the project . even though when i run that in react-native run-android it shows out the same error please to suggest some tips to trouble shoot this issue.

```
Android resource linking failed
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:136: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:138: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:139: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:143: error: resource android:color/white not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:150: error: resource android:color/white not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:151: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:163: error: resource android:color/white not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:164: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:181: error: resource android:color/black not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:772: error: resource android:color/transparent not found.
E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:967: error: resource android:color/transparent not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: Did you declare your color variables before using them ?

Comment: I do have a res file with colors.xml with declared color but facing the issue. iam new to react native i wanted to learn i installed android studio sdk etc and nodejs too

Comment: Can you add this file code to your question ? E:\reactapp\Demo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml

Comment: actually it does not have much of the code i created a empty activity project in android studio i get the same error . Then i created a new react native project using react-native init albums facing the same issue

Comment: did you modified the colors ? because black white and transparent doesn't exist you have to add them first